# Why to choose Apigee over Layer 7 for API Management

Tags: apigee

I want to understand what are the benefits of using Apigee if I already have Layer7 in place? Please let me know if which is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

Apigee is a very **'developer friendly**' API management platform.
Layer 7 has also API management functions.

With the *newest* version of Layer7 (spring 2017) the API management functions have *improved drastically*.

**Older version of Layer7**

If you have (an older version) of the Layer7 platform running in order to create your public APIs, and you need a full set of modern API management functions, you can choose to either upgrade Layer7 or add Apigee on-top.

**Api management team**

Another reason could be "separation of concerns" combined with "Conway's law". One department (or set of product teams) can deliver the APIs, the other teams can manage them. API management requires all kind of *governance tooling an processes*. If it is a small team that does the API management for your company (e.g. create the proxies, give support to external developers, maintain the developer portal) Apigee might be a fast and less complex alternative to Layer 7.

**Connectivity**

If the Layer7 platform has no external internet connectivity yet, the addition of a separate API management platform might be the fastest choice in an enterprise environment. You could to go for a separate Layer7 setup (separation of concerns) with the latest version (or go SaaS). This can leverage the Layer7 knowledge in your company. If the API management team has no Layer7 knowledge, Apigee could be a better choice because of its simplicity (Conway's Law).